# Saving int as key to an object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, key

Basically I have something that looks like this:

```
public class Inventory
{
public int ID { get; set; }
public Trade Have1 { get; set; }
public Trade Have2 { get; set; }
public Trade Have3 { get; set; }
}
```

And I want to be able to create and save an Inventory object using the IDs of Trade objects rather than having to have to pull the actual Trade object of each one as that seems pretty inefficient.

I would like to be able to do something like:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("AddToFT", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "realsubmit", role = "form" }))
     {
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Have1)
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Have2)
            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Have3)

         <input type="submit" value="Create" />
     }
```

So that I could just type in 3 integers of the Trade ID and then have it save those ints as the keys, rather than then having to pull each Trade from the database, put it into the Inventory object, and then save it. Something like this:

```
    [HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(Inventory inventory)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Pokemon.Add(inventory);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(inventory);
}
```

Perhaps I am looking at it the wrong way? Or is there a way to do this? Thanks a ton for any help!

Comment: Sorry, could you explain your issue in other words? I can't realize what you want achieved?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

Im the same as Alezis, cant really understand what you are trying to achieve where you are saying 'type' and are using hidden fields.

how about using:-

```
         <input type="text" name="haveId1" />
         <input type="text" name="haveId2" />
         <input type="text" name="haveId3" />
```

instead of hiddens, get the ids back and set them on a new object to save?

```
 [HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(int haveId1, int haveId2, int haveId2)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        Inventory inventory = new Inventory()
        {
            Have1 = haveId1,
            Have2 = haveId2,
            Have3 = haveId3
        };
        db.Pokemon.Add(inventory);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View();
}
```

Comment: That is no different to how he is already trying to insert the data, in-fact it's worse than how he is doing it. Also `ModelState.IsValid` is redundant within your code as no model is passed in to be validated, which was the purpose of `Inventory inventory`, not to mention the fact that it is more code. As long as those `Hidden Fields` are populated with data then the `Inventory inventory` parameter will hold the information they require.